# Error con Input - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un error cuando trato de usar un input en mi código, por alguna razón no me esta llevando la información al componente hijo a pesar de que si contiene información la variable que le mando.

**COMPONENTE PADRE**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cards">
        <app-cards *ngFor="let card of cards" [info]="card"></app-cards>
    </div>
</div>
```

**COMPONENTE HIJO**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PokeappService } from '../../services/pokeapp.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cards.component.sass'],
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemon: any = {};
  @Input() info: any = {};

  constructor(private pokeService: PokeappService) {
    this.pokeService.getPokemon('3').subscribe(pokemon => {
      this.pokemon = pokemon;
    });

    console.log(this.info); // Aquí deberia de mostrarme la info que envie.
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso puede ocurrir porque al nivel del constructor info todavía no recibe los datos si no hasta que carga el componente, trata de hacer el console.log dentro del ngOnInit

```
  <app-cards [info]="true"></app-cards>

  @Input() info: any = {};

  constructor() {
     // resultado {}
     console.log(this.info);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     // resultado true
     console.log(this.info);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

para solucionar este problema me costo pero es simple, solo utiliza este método:

```
ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(this.info);
  }
```

lo que hace este método es ejecutarse cada que detecta un cambio en los inputs.
Espero te funcione.